# How to hide UITableViewSections in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a static grouped table view that has 5 sections (all the sections have headers, no footers). I created all of this using a Storyboard. Now, how can I hide the first/top UITableViewSection (including the header). I tried making an outlet to the UITableViewSection but it tells me that it is not valid (undeclared type):

```
@IBOutlet var section: UITableViewSection!
```

I did it this way because I was planning on doing:

```
section.hidden = true
```

Can it not be done this way?

My delegates and data sources are set up 100% correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Swift 5:**

You can use the delegate method `heightForHeaderInSection`
:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 0.0
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

**Earlier than Swift 5**: Use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead of `UITableView.automaticDimension`

If it's not working with height `0.0`, use height `0.1`

If you want no cells in a particular section, use the delegate method:

```
func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int {
  if (section == 0) {
    return 0
  }
  else {
  // return the number of rows you want
  }
}
```

Or to a neater `switch-case` syntax:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 0.0
    default:
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

I tested both and they are working fine.

Comment: What if the TableView is static (a few hardcoded different from each other rows, like a settings window) ?

Comment: As of Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2: as an alternative to `tableView(_: heightForHeaderInSection)`, you can also override `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection)` and return `nil` when you want to hide the header. Then section heder height will be adjusted automatically to 0 to show no text.

Comment: Hiding the rows and setting rows as height 0 was causing issues with my constraints. This answer fixed that, nice solution! 

Comment: i have a condition on basis of this i have to hide one section can i hide tablesection based on condition inside ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear @sasquatch

Comment: @DilipTiwari Yes, you can. Write a new question and provide a link. I'll try to answer that.

Comment: `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is now `UITableView.automaticDimension` in Swift 5

Comment: does not work in ios15.5

Answer (score 10):

I also wish you could just make an `@IBOutlet` to a section and hide it, but sadly it seems not, so...

Based on various suggestions here, I've established the following, which doesn't require any interfering with explicit size values, and preserves whatever you may have set on a storyboard/XIB already. It just makes the header nil and row count 0 for any section you want to hide (which results in a size of `0.0`).

Obviously, you can configure `sectionShouldBeHidden` to work however you need; hiding #1 & #3 are just arbitrary examples.

**Swift v5**

```
private func sectionShouldBeHidden(_ section: Int) -> Bool {
    switch section {
    case 1, 3: return true
    default: return false
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if sectionShouldBeHidden(section) {
        return nil // Show nothing for the header of hidden sections
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section) // Use the default header for other sections
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if sectionShouldBeHidden(section) {
        return 0 // Don't show any rows for hidden sections
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) // Use the default number of rows for other sections
    }
}
```

Update: Unfortunately, the above is only enough if the style of the table view is `Plain`. When it's `Grouped`, there's also additional space added between each section, which needs taking care of too.
This extra space is the section's footer, so can be handled like so:

```
override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if sectionShouldBeHidden(section) {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude // Use the smallest possible value for hidden sections
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForFooterInSection: section) // Use the default footer height for other sections
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works best. It completely hides the sections and works well with an established tableView setup!

Comment: Using the `insetGrouped` table style I found I also had to override `tableView(_: heightForHeaderInSection:)`

Answer (score 7):

I tried all the solutions here with no success. At the end, adding these delegate methods  this one worked:

**Swift 5:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 4 ? 0 : return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return section == 4 ? 0.1 : super.tableView(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return section == 4 ? 0.1 super.tableView(tableView, heightForFooterInSection: section)
}
```

Note that you need to return 0.1 in height, returning 0 won't do it.

Answer (score 3):

0.0 did not work for me. I had to do this in order to make it work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 0.01
    default:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Zeezer. 0.0 also didn't work for me. I am wondering why tableView section. didn't like 0.0.

Comment: They need to have a specified value for the height, so 0.0 is not acceptable. If you do want to set the value to '0', then you need to use `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

Answer (score 2):

For group UITableView with static cells only this solution works:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let count = self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    if count == 0 {
        return CGFloat(Double.leastNormalMagnitude)
    }
    return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to hide sections because they are using a static grouped tableView with a dynamic number of sections, the solution below may be of help.  In my case, each section with data to display needed to have a custom header. Any section that did not have data, needed to be hidden fully.

The answer above was of great help in my scenario.  However, for those who don't always know which section(s) will need to be hidden here is a solution for you extending on the above.

In my scenario, I have up to 12 entries in an array that I want to show in up to 12 sections (amongst other sections in a grouped tableView).  If there are less than 12 entries to display, I want to hide the unnecessary sections by giving them 0 height and 0 rows.  I also wanted to hide the headerView.

To do this, I did the following:

1. Set up your tableView as per the excellent answer @sasquatch gave
   above.
2. In the numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) and tableView(_
   tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) functions, check whether the rows/height should be 0.

In my case, I was using sections 1 - 12 for my dynamic data so I used code as below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //For section 0 and 13, just 1 row is ok
    if section == 0 || section == 13 {
        return 1
    }

    //For sections 1 - 12, determine if we have data to populate it, or if we should hide it
    if section <= dynamicDataToDisplay.count {
        return 2
    }

    //If it's section 1 - 12, but we don't have a corresponding data entry in dynamicDataToDisplay, then just return 0 rows
    return 0

}
```

The code for the heightForHeader function is similar in logic:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    switch section {

    case 0:
        return 45.0
    case 13:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    default:
        if dynamicDataToDisplay.count >= section {
           return 25.0
        } else {
            return 0.0
        }

    } //end switch

}
```

Even after setting up these functions, I found that I was still getting headers appearing for the sections I wanted to hide.  I guess I thought that viewForHeaderInSection would not be called if the numberOfRows was 0 and heightOfHeader was also 0, but it was still being called.

Adding the following helped ensure that the header wasn't unnecessarily created:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    //set up header for dynamic data sections
    if 1 ... 12 ~= section  {

        if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        //Continue with the header set up for valid sections with rows to display data

        ......
    }
}
```

This solution might help anyone who is still getting a header being created despite its height and rows being set to 0.